# How to create a directory for each item in .xls sheet python

Tags: python

I need help, am trying to create a directory for each item(row) in a spreadsheet , how can i do that with python 3.5 .
 I tried installing pandas using pip and conda but it is not working, error saying I need  visual-c++-build-tools .Same error happen even after i installed the tools. .
 Is panda the best way to create directory for each row in .xls sheet? i have multiple .xls files

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in VBA? https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mkdir.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points of your question are not very clear to me, but I will try to provide you with some ideas.
You could make use of xlrd (documentation here: http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html ).

Let's assume you have a file 'sample.xls', with a number of sheets inside of it. For each sheet, you want to create as many folders in 'C:\test' (let's assume it's a Windows path) as the the number of rows in that sheet. Let's also assume you want to use the sheet's name followed by a progressive number
to name such folders (you can easily edit the code to fit your actual needs).

```
import os
from xlrd import open_workbook

parentPath = r"C:\test"
xlsFile = open_workbook('sample.xls') # Open the xls file
for sheetName in xlsFile.sheet_names(): # Loop over the sheets inside the xls file
    i = 1 # Initialize the index to be used in folder names
    for row in xlsFile.sheet_by_name(sheetName).col(0): # Select the first column and loop over the rows
        childPath = ''.join([sheetName, '_', str(i)])
        newPath = os.path.join(parentPath,childPath) 
        if not os.path.exists(newPath): # Make sure the path does not exist
            os.makedirs(newPath)
        i += 1
```

PS: I agree that using CSV files makes things a bit easier.

**EDIT:**

The following solution is based on the assumption you want to create as many folders as the number of (non-empty) cells in each sheet inside the xls file, and that each folder has name of the format 'sheetName_rowi_colj'
where i and j are two indices, which are related to cell position in the sheet.

```
import os
from xlrd import open_workbook

parentPath = r"C:\test"
xlsFile = open_workbook('sample.xls',ragged_rows=True) # Open the xls file
for sheetName in xlsFile.sheet_names(): # Loop over the sheets inside the xls file
    for rowIdx in range(xlsFile.sheet_by_name(sheetName).nrows): # Loop over the rows
        for colIdx in range(xlsFile.sheet_by_name(sheetName).row_len(rowIdx)): # Loop over the columns for each row
            if xlsFile.sheet_by_name(sheetName).cell_value(rowIdx,colIdx) != '': # Check if the cell is empty
                childPath = ''.join([sheetName, '_row', str(rowIdx+1), '_col', str(colIdx+1)]) # +1 because indices start from zero
                newPath = os.path.join(parentPath,childPath) 
                if not os.path.exists(newPath): # Make sure the path does not exist
                    os.makedirs(newPath)
```

If you have a number of xls files, just loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file as a CSV this task will be much easier. Try this:

```
import csv, sys, os

folder_list = []
with open('folders.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            if item != None:
                folder_list.append(item)
                print item

for folder in folder_list:
    try:
        os.makedirs(folder)
    except WindowsError as e:
        pass
```